# Как получить полный список сделок crm.deal.list при помощи python за текущий год так чтобы Битрикс не заблокировал аккаунт из-за нагрузки данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, битрикс24

Мне необходимо настроить ежедневную перезагрузку данных по сделкам битрикса (метод crm.deal.list) так чтобы Битрикс не заблокировал аккаунт? Ранее уже была попытка выгрузки, и Битрикс заблочил мой вебхук ссылаясь на чрезмерную нагрузку системы. Я вроде нашел библиотеку которая не будет нагружать систему не не уверен в корректности работы ее.

Скрипт выглядит так

````
from bitrix24 import *
# pip install bitrix24-rest
import pandas
import os
import smtplib


try:
    os.remove('D:\\Bitrix\\crm.deal.list\\crmdeallist.csv')

    bx24 = Bitrix24('https://bitrix.domain/rest/11111/webhookkey')
    headers = ['ID', 'DATE', 'STATUS']

    result = bx24.callMethod('crm.deal.list', select=headers)

    filtered_result = []

    for el in result:
        new_el = dict()
        for name in el:
            new_el[name] = el[name]
        filtered_result.append(new_el)

    data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(filtered_result, columns=headers)
    data_frame.to_csv(r'D:\\Bitrix\\crm.deal.list\\crmdeallist.csv', encoding='utf-16', index=False, mode='a')```

Не совсем ясно где указывать фильтр по текущему году, и не блокирует ли битрикс запрос сделанный с помощью этой библиотеки?
````

Comment: У [этого метода](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/crm/cdeals/crm_deal_list.php) есть параметр `filter`, а у сделки — [поле](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/crm/cdeals/crm_deal_fields.php) `DATE_CREATE`. Поэкспериментируйте с фильтром

Comment: Попробуйте так: `'>=DATE_CREATE' => '01.01.2022 00:00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

`pip install fast-bitrix24`

```py
from fast_bitrix24 import Bitrix

bx = Bitrix(
    '<your webhook link>'
)

# noinspection PyTypeChecker
deals = bx.list_and_get(
    'crm.deal'
)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось добавить фильтр и прописать дату. filter={'>DATE_CREATE': '2022-01-01 00:00:00'}. А можно ли в данном случае прописывать несколько фильтров? Если мне например нужен один фильтр по дате, а второй по статусу?

Comment: @DDDD, `list_and_get` предназначен для получения полного списка сущностей и не поддерживает параметры bitrix (фактически этот метод был добавлен специально для миграции). Его преимущества это получение большого количества записей за короткий промежуток времени. У этой библиотеки есть метод `get_all` вот его рассмотрите подробней. Он поддерживает все параметры запросов bitrix